# MVC3 Custom attribute to deny HTTP Verbs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

In Asp.net web application we can use below line of code in web.config file to deny HttpVerbs but MVC uses action controller for routing and Authorize attribute for authorization.

So we would like to create custom attribute to handle this.

How to create custom attribute to deny some HTTP Verbs by default on all action methods and only allow HTTPGet and HTTPPost.

```
<deny verbs="*" users="*" />
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to disallow all verbs **except** GET and POST, you can do the following in your web.config file.

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <security>
   <requestFiltering>
    <verbs allowUnlisted="false">
     <add verb="GET" allowed="true" />
     <add verb="POST" allowed="true" />
    </verbs>
   </requestFiltering>
  </security>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Example code and other reading [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/use-request-filtering)

By placing this in the web.config, you can "short circuit" the .NET pipeline and allow IIS to choose if it should respond to the request or not (which is more efficient for your application).

Comment: Thanks. Given example can be configured in IIS but we have to configure in MVC application since we do not have control over the server.

Comment: You have a web.config in your MVC app solution.  You can make this change there

Comment: Yes, we can but  MVC uses Action Controller pipeline for authorization so been asked to create Custom attribute to enforce all the action methods.

Comment: @Ask_SO - I still don't understand what MVC routing and authorization have to do with HTTP Verbs?  Besides, MVC *already* has built in attributes for `HTTPGet` and `HTTPPost`....just decorate all of your action methods with these.  If you want to block any verbs that are not allowed, you really really should do that at the configuration level.